# Why does the url not resolve to the correct folder on the ubuntu12.10/apache2 server

Tags: server, apache2

I can't figure out why the url hello.apoio.co resolves to the var/www/ folder and not the var/www/hello.apoio.co folder

I'm sure it's something simple but I can't see it? I followed the official instructions to the letter. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is the code from the virtual host file

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/hello.apoio.co/
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/hello.apoio.co/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual host file shows path to some directory which must be accessible by Apache2.

I assume that you want to access this directory by typing `http://hello.apoio.co` in broswer, if this is the case then it should be a [`ServerName`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) directive inside the virtual host file.

So the file you posted must become:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hello.apoio.co
    ServerAlias www.hello.apoio.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hello.apoio.co/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/hello.apoio.co/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In the above virtual host configuration ServerName and ServerAlias are used to set the corresponding URL and its aliases.

Further information [Using Name-based Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)

Comment: @user1018853 If the problem is solved consider [marking the answer as accepted](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)